# ActiveX control in Java

Tags: java, activex

Is it possible to host/embed an ActiveX control in Java? 
Would the ActiveX embedded Java program be cross platform compatible?

Answer (score 2):

See [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/beans/axbridge/developerguide/index.html) for using ActiveX in Java. Also note the Java version. I don't know if later editions support this.

ActiveX controls are not cross-platform, so nothing that uses them is either. See the supported platform list on the linked page.